# Yocto Build edk2 recipe giving error in Ubuntu: 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: embedded, yocto, edk2

When I try to run the Yocto build with this Build Configuration

BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"

I am using Ubuntu: 20.04.6 LTS
I am getting error

| expr: syntax error: missing argument after ‘>=’

There was a compiler warning thrown as an error in the Ed2 recipe, so I manually edited the makefile. and also I have installed the package libncurses5